# Can't set property of a UIView class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a `UIView` class:

```cxx
class FlashCard: UIView {

var linkedMemory: Memory? {
    didSet {
        frontView = showContent(of: linkedMemory!.front)
        backView = showContent(of: linkedMemory!.back)
    }
}
var frontView = UIView()
var backView = UIView()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

func showContent(of linkedMemory: Any) -> UIView {
    var contentView = UIView()
    if let image = linkedMemory as? UIImage {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = image
        contentView = imageView
    }
    if let text = linkedMemory as? String {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.text = text
        contentView = label
    }
    return contentView
}

}
```

I'm trying to set its `linkedMemory` property in a view controller that contains this view:

```cxx
@IBOutlet weak var flashCardView: FlashCard!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    calcGroupFamiliarity()
    flashCardView.linkedMemory = Memory(masteryLevel: 1, algorithm: Algorithm.algorithm1.chooseAlgorithm(), forgetRatio: 0, lastStudyTime: Date(), front: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ideas-Blue"), back: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ideas-Yellow"))
    // See? I'm trying to change flashCardView's property here, but it never changes :(
}
```

Anybody has any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the screen shot showing? What do you expect it to show?

Comment: You want to access the property of UIVew class?

Comment: @User511 I want to set the property

Comment: You mean in this line ---     flashCardView.linkedMemory = Memory(masteryLevel: 1, algorithm: Algorithm.algorithm1.chooseAlgorithm(), forgetRatio: 0, lastStudyTime: Date(), front: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ideas-Blue"), back: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ideas-Yellow"))
?

Comment: Will you please add your memory class  code as well?

Comment: @Paulw11 I added a little description, I expect the `front` and `back` value of `linkedMemory` to be `UIImage`